# Binding XML to Grid in VB.NET

Tags: xml, vb.net, xmlreader

I have following data into XML file and I want to display in grid. 
I am going to bind this data to a grid through data table. 
I am confused about the reading the nodes and adding the row to data table. 
How can I do it ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Employees>
  <Employee>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <FirstName>Prakash</FirstName>
    <LastName>Rangan</LastName>
    <Salary>70000</Salary>
  </Employee>
  <Employee>
    <ID>5</ID>
    <FirstName>Norah</FirstName>
    <LastName>Miller</LastName>
    <Salary>21000</Salary>
  </Employee>
  <Employee>
    <ID>17</ID>
    <FirstName>Cecil</FirstName>
    <LastName>Walker</LastName>
    <Salary>60000</Salary>
  </Employee>
</Employees>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Protected Sub btnReadXmlFile_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

     Dim filePath As String = Server.MapPath("~/Employees.xml")

     'Employee Must match with the element name in 

     'your file

     Dim dt As New DataTable("Employee")



     'Add Columns in datatable

     'Column names must match XML File nodes

     dt.Columns.Add("ID", GetType(System.Integer))

     dt.Columns.Add("FirstName", GetType(System.String))

     dt.Columns.Add("LastName", GetType(System.String))

     dt.Columns.Add("Salary", GetType(System.Integer))


     'Read XML File And Display Data in GridView

     dt.ReadXml(filePath)

     GridView1.DataSource = dt

     GridView1.DataBind()

End Sub
```